# How to use stuff defined inside a condition

Tags: java

I have this method in Java:

```
public void noExcelToExcel(String a) {
    char[] noExcel = a.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (noExcel[i] == 'C') {

            char[] lin = new char[i - 1];
            a.getChars(1, i, lin, 0);

            char[] col = new char[i - 1];
            a.getChars(i + 1, a.length(), col, 0);

            break;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

I created 2 new char arrays ("lin" and "col") which I can only know the length after this loop/if, so I cannot define them before that. How do I "store" them in memory so that I can use them elsewhere, inside or outside this method? Thanks!

Comment: You can define `char[] lin;` before `lin = new char[i-1];`. For more basics, take the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Yes, that is a nice suggestion. If(myWay<yourWay){ code.reWrite} ;)  Abraço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the variables before your loop body to use them later:

```java
public void noExcelToExcel(String a) {
    char[] noExcel = a.toCharArray();
    char[] lin = null;
    char[] col = null;

    for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (noExcel[i] == 'C') {

            lin = new char[i - 1];
            a.getChars(1, i, lin, 0);

            col = new char[i - 1];
            a.getChars(i + 1, a.length(), col, 0);

            break;
        }
    }

    if (lin == null || col == null) {
        // will be reached if there was no 'C' in noExcel
    }

    // do something with lin and col ...
}
```

Note that the condition inside the loop may not be met, so you have to check for that afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense (facepalm) :) The condition will surely be met but that's taken care of in the rest of the code.

Comment: But of course, that goes against the single responsibility principle. You should do ONE thing in a method, not 3 or 5 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways, one could be to change the signature of the method to:

```
public char[][] noExcelToExcel(String a) {
```

and now you simply put `lin` and `col` into a two-dim array.

Or you use some `Pair` class. Alternatively: why not have **two** methods?!
One returns the `lin` result, the other `col`. Sure, that means iterating twice, but you then have two nicely named methods, and each one returns one thing.

Beyond that, you could make `lin` and `col` fields of the surrounding class.

Thing is: there are really many ways to solve this problem. So, the real answer is: start playing. You learn programming by *trying* things.

Comment: Thanks! I actually thought about doing it in 2 separate methods; will give it a try for the sake of practice.

Comment: @JorgeCardoso Not only for the sake of practice. Read about the "single responsibility principle". You want that each and any method does exactly **one** thing. Not multiple things like "first filling two arrays, then process first array, then second array or so".